# How is the curl of the electric field possible?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, potential, maxwell-equations, vector-fields

Taking the curl of the electric field must be possible, because Faraday's law involves it:
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = - \partial \mathbf{B} / \partial t$$
But I've just [looked on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Curl_of_the_gradient), where it says

> The curl of the gradient of any twice-differentiable scalar field $\phi$ is always the zero vector:
> $$\nabla \times (\nabla \phi)=\mathbf{0}$$

Seeing as $\mathbf{E} = - \nabla V$, where $V$ is the electric potential, this would suggest $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = \mathbf{0}$.

What presumably monumentally obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: As time derivative in the Faraday's law indicates the field there is not static, it does not therefore have to be conservative, i.e. a gradient of a scalar field.

Comment: This is a FAQ. Not all electrostatic formulas hold in electromagnetism. Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100028/2451

Comment: You're missing the fact that electric field cannot always be expressed as the gradient of a scalar function!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The fact is that, in the general case
$$
\vec{E} = -\vec{\nabla}V - \frac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial t};
$$
(signs depend on conventions used) where $\vec{A}$ is called *vector potential*. You can consult for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_potential).

Let us consider homogeneous Maxwell equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{B} = 0,\\
\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E} + \frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t} = 0;
\end{cases}
$$

It is well-known that every divergenceless filed on $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be written a curl of another vector field just as we know that a curless field can be written as a gradient of a scalar function on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Thus from the first equation,

$$
\vec{B} = \vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A},
$$

and substituting this in the second equation,

$$
\vec\nabla\times\left(\vec{E} + \frac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial t}\right)=0,
$$

since one can exchange the curl with the derivative w.r.t. time, and so one can set:

$$
\vec{E} + \frac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial t} = -\vec\nabla V,
$$

from which

$$
\vec{E} = -\vec{\nabla}V - \frac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial t}.
$$

Note that if your magnetic field is time-independent, you recover the well-know formula

$$
\vec{E} = -\vec\nabla V.
$$

Comment: "It is well-known that every divergenceless filed can be written a curl of another vector field (in a simply connected domain)." Actually, **no**: this is a common misconception. Divergence-free implies a vector potential in regions *with vanishing second de Rham cohomology*, NOT in simply connected domains. Take $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus the origin. That region is simply connected, and yet there exist divergenceless fields on it that do not, in fact, admit a vector potential. Simple connectedness is relevant for curl-free fields to be gradients, but not for divergence-free fields.

Answer (score 16):

When there is a time-varying magnetic field, the electric field is non-conservative and therefore cannot be written in the form $\mathbf{E}=-\nabla V$.

Answer (score 6):

For dynamic electric and magnetic fields, there is a piece of the electric field that depends on the vector potential:
$$
\vec{E} = - \vec{\nabla} V - \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}, \qquad \vec{B} = \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{A}.
$$
Taking the curl of the first equation yields Faraday's Law (with the $V$-dependent term dropping out as you note);  taking the divergence of the second one yields the "no monopole" law $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B} = 0$.